# Idiomatic way to add a u8 to i8

Tags: rust

Consider the following code:

```
let mut val : u8 = 125;
let deltas : [i8; 4] = [5, -5, 5, 5];

let delta = select_current_delta(deltas);

val += delta;
```

This seems simple. I want to either increase or decrease a byte value based on some criteria (and I have a way to prevent overflow of a `u8` value).

This, of course, does not compile:

```
 > rustc lala.rs
 lala.rs:7:12: 7:17 error: mismatched types:
  expected `u8`,
     found `i8`
 (expected u8,
     found i8) [E0308]
 lala.rs:7     val += delta;
                      ^~~~~
```

Duh! Mixing signed and unsigned types seems to be forbidden in Rust. How about this?

```
val = (val as i8 + delta) as u8;
```

This compiles, but when I try to run it...

```
> ./lala
thread '<main>' panicked at 'arithmetic operation overflowed', lala.rs:7
```

Yeah, `i8`'s max value is 125, adding 5 will overflow, even though the value is perfectly fine for `u8`.

I was able come up with two solutions that work:

```
val = (val as i16 + delta as i16) as u8;
// or
if delta < 0 { val -= (-delta) as u8 }
else { val += delta as u8}
```

Neither of those seem elegant to me. Is there an idiomatic way to add a u8 to a i8?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is there an idiomatic way to add a `u8` to a `i8`?

The problem of adding a `u8` to a `i8` (with `+`) is: what type should the result be? Neither `u8` or `i8` is better, and using `i16` while correct would probably be surprising.

Thus, for now, mixed-integrals operands are not supported. The idiomatic way is to cast both operands to a common type, which will also be the type of the result. This is already what you are doing.

> But, what of `u8 += i8` ?

Unfortunately, at the moment, this is sugar for `u8 = u8 + i8` and therefore has all the limitations of `+` even though the result type would not be an issue.

As all annoying limitations of Rust, there's a RFC for it! This is [PR #953: Overloaded Assignment Operations](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/953). This RFC is in final comment period so a decision is expected soon, and hopefully this means that it will be accepted and Rust will gain support for mixed-integrals assignment operations.

---

As a personal preference, for now, I would go for:

```
val = (val as i16 + delta as i16) as u8;
```

which avoids the branch.

Comment: If I write `val += delta`, it's pretty evident what a result type should be. I would be OK to use an `unsafe` block in this particular case to let the compiler know that I know what I'm doing.

Comment: @Tomo: Ah, yes, sorry... you've hit a limitation of `+=` at the moment, but a RFC in final comment period is about to change things :)

Comment: Cool. Which RFC number is this?

Comment: @Tomo: My bad, I should have only commented *after* I edited ^^

Answer (score 10):

You can do this to avoid the overflow and wrap the addition:

```
val = (val as i8).wrapping_add(delta) as u8;
```

[Look here for all the arithmetic operations](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.u8.html#method.wrapping_add)

Comment: Thanks for the link to the arithmetic operations! I wasn't aware of them.